# Can I desolder the internal memory from a Samsung Galaxy SIII and move it to a Samsung Galaxy SII?

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, hardware, internal-sd

My SGIII phone has an issue with the main board and will not start at all. Can I desolder the internal memory and move it to a Samsung Galaxy SII?

Or is there any other way to retrieve the information from the internal memory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this and this answer is based on this [XDA thread -Soldering? Move internal memory chip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/hardware-hacking) which can give you some pointers

- EMMC is a BGA chip, which means you require specialised equipment and expertise to deal with it
- IMEI information is stored in EMMC and CPU for Samsung phones. If you simply remove this chip and place in another device, IMEI mismatch will prevent radio (calling, SMS) to work, but you may be able to recover data stored
- Encryption is the biggest hurdle (if your device was encrypted), even if you tackle the hardware portion. Your encryption keys are tied to the device and even if you remember the password on the old device and use the same, you may not be able to access data

Using JTAG , it may be possible to revive or locate and repair the fault. Again, buying JTAG, manipulating it's controller, transferring information etc is again for a professional or a serious hobbyist (I did try to learn this when I had a Note 2 to fix battery draining motherboard and found it too involved, though I didn't need to spend anything)

Bottom line - it's best dealt with repair  or data recovery professionals and not something trivial . But then, if you are upto to it, go ahead and share your experience here for the benefit of community :)

**Edit** Google will tell you that both chips are different. For S3 it is `KMVTU000LM-B50` and S2 `KMV3U000LM-B304`

*Establish if they can be interchanged?* (Not within the ambit of this site) and then proceed. There can be many variations, footprint of the chip, pin connections, architecture, voltages etc which could prevent you from doing what you want

Comment: This is as far as I'm aware a Samsung Galaxy S3. Does it have a EMMC chip?

Comment: Also, to answer your question: No, it was not encrypted.

Comment: 1. Yes, [it has](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=galaxy+s3+emmc+chip+price&oq=galaxy+s3+emmc&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l3.13610j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) eMMC chip 2. Not being encrypted rules out one problem

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this looks more like an S4 than an S III.

Memory chip pin-out and placement are heavily device-specific. What's more, older devices such as S II have distinct (individually packaged) SoC and eMMC chips, while all newer ones like S4 use chip-on-chip packaging (e.g. ePOP, as demonstrated in [this previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176276/replace-internal-memory/176277#176277) I wrote - could also serve as a reference). This denies you any possibilities of transferring the chip itself.

For other means of recovery, @beeshyams already covered it well.

Comment: +1. I had read your earlier answer but forgot :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's a Samsung Galaxy S3, not model S4.

Comment: @Vesa The picture you attached, if it's captured by yourself rather than attached, says otherwise. Amongst various easy-to-spot differences, S3 has a large bottom bezel which the home key doesn't fully fill (height); S4 has a thin bottom bezel filled by the home key.